# can I organize method definition order inside a single file somehow?

Tags: f#

I want to define helper methods below the methods that consume them, is there a way to do this in a single file in F#? cluttering up the top of the file with stuff that is closer to implementation details, instead of the actual primary high level purpose is not making me happy. Reasoning for the limitation of a single file: doing most of my f# in LinqPad.

Extension methods at the top is also ugly to me.

where in C# I could declare a main that didn't try to run or compile until the other methods in the file were compiled

Comment: You would generally deal with this by putting the helper methods in a separate file/module and `open`ing it. You are being severely limited by LinqPad.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of text editor is currently holding you back. As @Daniel noted in the comments, generally you don't clutter your main implementation file with helpers, but instead put them in a separate file and open the file.

F# forces you to declare functions before you use them, so you must implement the helpers before you implement the calling functions.  Many F# developers consider this a feature rather than a problem since it gives all F# files a logical order and a simple way of finding the starting point for understanding how the logic in the file works.

My suggestion would be to start reading your files in the opposite order (and ditch LinqPad as your primary text editor for F#).  You have to put the most dependent function last, so start reading files from the bottom first.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons why this is very much the wrong approach:

http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/

F# doesn't support this behavior at all on purpose.

*Let's start with detection. There are a number of tools to help you detect circular dependencies in your code.*

- *If you're using C#, you will need a tool like the invaluable NDepend.*
- *And if you are using Java, there are equivalent tools such as JDepend.*
- *But if you are using F#, you're in luck! You get circular dependency detection for free!*

*"Very funny," you might say, "I already know about F#'s circular dependency prohibition -- it's driving me nuts! What can I do to fix the problem and make the compiler happy?"*